# Apollo Client + Next.js not sending non-SSR requests

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I'm having an issue where only the requests that are made on the server side are being sent through by Apollo Client. To my understanding, there needs to be a client made on initialization in the `_app` file for non-SSR requests, and another whenever there's an SSR request needed. So I'm using the code below to create those:

```js
export function createApolloClient(ssrMode = typeof window === 'undefined') {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode,
    uri: process.env.API_ENDPOINT,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
}

export function useApollo() {
  return useMemo(() => createApolloClient(false), []);
}
```

and In my `_app.tsx`:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const client = useApollo();
  // ...
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Modal />
        <Toast />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

and this is all fine for server-side requests and I can retrieve the results. The problem is with non-SSR requests such as the one below where I get **no response and in fact no request is being sent when I check using Dev Tools.**

```js
const [signUp, { loading }] = useMutation(SIGNUP);
const handleSubmit = () => {
   signUp({
        variables: {
          payload: {
            ...state.inputs,
          },
        },
      })
      .then((res)=>console.log(res),
            (err)=>console.error(err));
}
```

All I get in this case is, `undefined` getting logged. Doing the same thing using `async/await` syntax doesn't change much either and in fact it doesn't seem to reach the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with using `process.env.API_ENDPOINT` for creating the apollo client; as there's no access to the environment variables on client-side.